# Is it possible to list the content of of Zip archive that's within another Zip archive?

Tags: php, zip

I know how to read and iterate files inside a zip archive. But I want to iterate through the content of nested Zip files (zip file inside another zip file) without having to extract them first. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: No; if you could do that, you wouldn't need to extract the containing ZIP in the first place :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two zip files are just storing collections of files then yes you can because no compression or other obfuscation has been applied. In order to do this you would want to apply your `reading and iterating over files inside a zip archive` method to the initial zip archive and check to see if any of the files is a zip archive. If you find a zip archive then just apply your `reading and iterating over files inside a zip archive` method again.

If compression has been applied then no you can't because you're essentially attempting to view the contents of a compressed stream of data that is within another compressed stream of data. You'd have to decompress the first one and then decompress the second one.

This assumes that you can zip files without applying any compression, which I believe is true.